# For a hypersurface seperating a connected manifold, prove the existence of a smooth vector field that is nowhere tangent (to the hypersurface)

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, surfaces, connectedness, vector-fields

Let $M^{m}$ be a connected smooth manifold and let $\Sigma^{m-1} \subset M$ be a smooth hypersurface that seperates M into two connected components. Prove that there exists a smooth vector field $X$ on M, such that $X(p) \not \in T_p(\Sigma^{m-1})\: \forall p \in \Sigma^{m-1}$.

My ideas so far:
I chose countably many slice-charts $\{(U_i,\phi_i)\}_{i\in I}$ that cover M, i.e. such that $\phi_i(U_i \cap \Sigma^{m-1})=\mathbb{R}^{m-1}\times\{0\}$.
That means $\phi_i(U_i \setminus \Sigma^{m-1}) = \mathbb{R}^m_+ \cup \mathbb{R}^m_-. $
Therefore $U_i$ itself consists of two connected components $C_i^+, C_i^-$.
I then chose $X = \pm \frac{\partial}{\partial{x^{m}}}\cdot \psi(x)$. Plus in $C_i^+$ and minus in $C_i^-$ where $\psi$ is a smooth bump function supported in $M\setminus \Sigma$. But then I didn't know how to expand this beyond one chart. Maybe using a partition of unity ?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You can use a partition of unity in a neighborhood of $\Sigma$ and then extend the vector field by $0$ outside this neighbourhood, this should work. I have another solution in mind, but this makes use of Riemannian metrics. Do you know this notion?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately I am pretty new to differential geometry so no.  I don't quite understand your proposal for using the partition of unity to extend the vector field to $0$ away from $\Sigma$. My problem was that the vector field may not be well-defined on the intersection of two charts. Since $\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_m}}$ can point into different directions on two different charts.

Comment: They might point into different direction, but since they are both transverse to $\Sigma$ and point in the same direction, their gluing thanks to a partition of unity is transverse and points in that direction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But say we have a point $p \in \Sigma$ that lies in the intersection of two charts. Couldn't it be that the contributions from each chart from the partition of unity cancel each other, leaving me with $0$ ? And $0$ would then be in the tangent-space of $\Sigma$

Comment: Since partitions of unity are positive functions, this cannot happen

Comment: Elaborating a bit more: show that if two tangent vectors $u,v \in T_pM$, with $p \in \Sigma$, are such that a chart $\phi$, $\langle \phi_*u,\partial/\partial x^m\rangle >0$ and $\langle \phi_*v,\partial/\partial x^m\rangle >0$, then so is any positive combination of $u$ and $v$. Generalize this to a finite combination, and use this to glue your local vector fields pointing toward $C^+$ into a global vector field pointing toward $C^+$.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Didier
I want to try to solve the problem now:\

First I cover $\Sigma$ with countably many slice-charts $\{(U_i,\phi_i)\}_{i \in I}$ such that $\phi_i(U_i \cap \Sigma) = \mathbb{R}^{m-1} \times \{0\} \:\forall i \in I$.
That means $\phi_i(U_i \setminus \Sigma^{m-1}) = \mathbb{R}^m_+ \cup \mathbb{R}^m_-. $
Therefore $U_i$ itself consists of two connected components $C_i^+, C_i^-$. With $C_i^+$ being mapped to $\mathbb{R}^m_+$ and $C_i^-$ to $\mathbb{R}^{m}_-$.
Further all components on one side of the hyperplane should get a + and all components on the other side a minus sign. This can be achieved by inverting the last component $\phi_i^m$ if necessary.

I define the vector-field $X_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial{x^m}}$ locally. (Pointing from $C_i^-$ to $C_i^+$).
I then take a partition of unity $(\rho_i)_{i \in I}$ subordinate to the given cover of $\Sigma$. Then $X:=\sum_{i \in I}\rho_i\cdot X_i$ is clearly a smooth global vector field. I check that it is nowhere tangent to $\Sigma$. Let $p \in \Sigma$. Since the supports of the $\rho_i$ are locally-finite, there exists an open neighbourhood U of p such that only finitely many $\rho_1,...,\rho_n$ are nonzero in U. Say now the chart $\phi_1$ contains p. Since $\phi_{1*}$ is an isomorphism of tangent-spaces, it suffices to show that the m-th component of $\phi_{1*}(X)$ is nonzero. $\phi_{1*}(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\rho_i(p)\cdot \phi_{1*}(X_i)$ where all $\rho_i(p) \geq 0$.
I can write $\phi_{1*}(X_i) = \phi_{1*}(\phi_{i*}^{-1}\cdot \phi_{i*}(X_i)) = \phi_{1*}\cdot\phi_{i*}^{-1}(e_m)$.
Now it should follow that the m-th component of $\phi_{1*}\cdot\phi_{i*}^{-1}(e_m) \: $is > $0$ with the chosen orientations.(And that should finish the proof). But I am struggling to show this rigorously.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Careful: you don't have any notion of inner product in $M$ to talk about $\langle X_j, T_p\Sigma\rangle$. You only have such objects on $\Bbb R^m$, that is in charts. What is important is that in charts, vectors pointing toward $C^\{+}$ (resp. $C^-$) are exactly given by vectors such that $\langle v,e_m\rangle >0$ (resp. $<0$) if the chart is well chosen.

Comment: I tried to correct my mistake...but that didn't quite work out